# Il a le sens de l'humour VS Il a un sens de l'humour

Tags: articles, articles-definis

> Il a **le** sens de l'humour.
>
> Il a **un** sens de l'humour.

I was wondering about the difference in meaning between using "un" or "le". I tried searching for both versions and they were both used for the same sentence.

Personally, I feel that "un" is more appropriate though because we are talking about humour in general.

Like we say in English: *He has **a** good sense of humour*. Unless we really want to specify it or we are talking about one that's already been mentioned in the conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form is the most usual one.

Here *sens de l'humour* is seen as something you have or you haven't. It is assumed there is just one *sens de l'humour*.

If you say *il a **un** sens de l'humour*, you mean the person has something that looks like the *sens de l'humour* but isn't the mainstream one. That would be more like:

> *Il a un sens de l'humour particulier.*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to **[user jlliagre's](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43993/17649)** answer I'll add the following.
It is possible to speak of "**un sens de l'humour**" on the condition that "sens" be modified by an adjective; however, few adjectives might be idiomatic. The adjective "**grand**" is.

- Ils ont un grand sens de l'humour. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grand+sens+de+l%27humour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrand%20sens%20de%20l%27%20humour%3B%2Cc0), [ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22grand%20sens%20de%20l%27humour%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr))

As illogical as it may seem "[un petit sens de l'humour](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=petit+sens+de+l%27humour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)" is not said; it seems that if some people are deemed able of possessing that quality to a great extent, then there  should be others endowed with the possession of it  in moderate quantities, but no, apparently this is not so: either you possess a normal understanding of humour or you possess it to a great extent or not at all; here is then another mystery of French linguistics to which one should not yet despair of finding a satisfying explanation despite the apparently irremediable nonsensical  situation.

It'll be possible to speak of a very mediocre sense of humour using this process of adjectival modification, the idiomatic adjective being "**piètre**".

- ([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GIZOSVfPnOQC&pg=PT38&dq=%22pi%C3%A8tre+sens+de%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5k-Oo1eTtAhUhxYUKHbr-DEEQ6AEwBnoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22pi%C3%A8tre%20sens%20de%22&f=false))  Le silence se prolongeait, devenait insupportable. — Je plaisantais, Will, répéta-t-elle. Mon piètre sens de l'humour m'a encore joué des tours ! Désolée.

I suppose, from a certain experience that I have of the French language, that in order to supply a replacement for "petit", which as well as not being in Google books does not seem idiomatic to me, one can use "**modeste**", but I have no supporting reference.

- Un modeste sens de l'humour ne lui fait certainement pas défaut mais elle avait tendance à vouloir trop  en faire.

A careful search will probably yield other useful idiomatic combinations.

Comment: "Un sens de l'humour" also fits if there is a relative clause that defines "sens de l'humour", like an adjective does. Ex: *il a un sens de l'humour qui ne plait pas à tout le monde*.

Comment: @Greg The relative clause appears to be the best way to describe any particular aspect. This can be the point of one more answer.